# Set Text at tabhost - Android

Tags: android, android-tabhost

How can I change the name of *tabhost* tab automatically?

```
TabHost tmp = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
tmp.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).findViewById(android.R.id.title).setText("Test");
```

`SetText(string)` is undefined for the text view, why?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To change the text of tabs, you need to get the view **i.e** TextView which is set as title of tabs and you can change it like this:

```
TabHost tabhost = getTabHost();
for(int i=0;i<tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildCount();i++) 
{
    TextView tv = (TextView) tabhost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).findViewById(android.R.id.title);
    tv.setText(.....);
}
```

For More information About TabHost refer this Link
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html

Comment: Whats about if we need two textviews as the title of the Tabs?? like http://imgur.com/9ekZ4qc

Answer (score 0):

```
LinearLayout rLayout = (LinearLayout) tmp.getTabWidget().getChildAt(Pos_of_ur_tab_in_tab_widget_for_which_text_to_changed);
((TextView)rLayout.getChildAt(position_of_ur_textview_child_in_tab_layout)).setText("your_text");
```